# Change TintColor of the UIImageView in moreNavigationController

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have this code to customize my moreNavigationController:

```
UITableView *tView = (UITableView*)tabController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
if ([[tView subviews] count]) {
    for (UITableViewCell *cCell in [tView visibleCells]) {
        cCell.textLabel.textColor = TABLECELL_TEXT_COLOR;
        cCell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = TABLECELL_TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHTED;
        cCell.contentView.backgroundColor = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
        cCell.backgroundColor = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
        UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        UIColor *uicCell = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR_SELECTED
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:uicCell];
        [cCell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
    }
}
```

And I have changed the images of my TabBar to Gray and Green but when I click over the more button this is the result:

[image]

I don't understand why is blue, so I have tried to change the tint color but nothing seams to work.

I have added this code to my function:

```
UIImageView *imgV = cCell.imageView;
imgV.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[imgV setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIImageView *imgV2 = imgV;
```

And this is what I can see in the variables:

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try it --- image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

Comment: put that code in

`viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Thanks to all, I have tried both approach alone and together and the image is blue instead of red

Comment: try to set tintColor of Cell

Comment: I have tried cCell.tintColor and cCell.contentView.tintColor and is the same result, I'm starting to get frustrated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying a lot this is the final code:

```
UITableView *tView = (UITableView*)tabController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
UIColor *tViewColor = MORE_TINTCOLOR;
[tView setTintColor: tViewColor];
if ([[tView subviews] count]) {
    for (UITableViewCell *cCell in [tView visibleCells]) {
        cCell.textLabel.textColor = TABLECELL_TEXT_COLOR;
        cCell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = TABLECELL_TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHTED;
        cCell.contentView.backgroundColor = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
        cCell.backgroundColor = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
        UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        UIColor *uicCell = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR_SELECTED
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:uicCell];
        [cCell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
    }
}
```

you have to change the UITableView TintColor.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a the solution for **Swift 5**:

Add the following in `viewDidLoad` of the  subclass of `UITabBarController`

```
if let topViewController = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController {
    if let tableView = topViewController.view as? UITableView {
        tableView.tintColor = .accent
    }
}
```

[image]